# How to use Flutter to build a bottom sheet widget which is able to drag up to full screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation

I want to build a bottom sheet widget which is able to drag up to full screen.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Google map has a widget is able to do this. Here is the screenshot (check attached image):

**Before drag up:**

[image: Bottom sheet with drag up button]
**After drag up:**

[image: Bottom sheet after drag up]

Comment: Did you get a solution for this

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `DraggableBottomSheet` widget with the `Stack` widget:

[image: Google Maps Draggable Sheet]

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rohan20/869492358cbb15311538f069a0c749af) for the entire page in this^ GIF, or try the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rohantaneja/pen/JjYgPzm).

Here's the structure of the entire page:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomGoogleMap(),
          CustomHeader(),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.30,
            minChildSize: 0.15,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: CustomScrollViewContent(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the `Stack`:

 - The Google map is the lower most layer.

 - The Header (search field + horizontally scrolling chips) is above the map.

 - The DraggableBottomSheet is above the Header.

Some useful parameters as defined in `draggable_scrollable_sheet.dart`:

```dart
  /// The initial fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.5`.
  final double initialChildSize;

  /// The minimum fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.25`.
  final double minChildSize;

  /// The maximum fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `1.0`.
  final double maxChildSize;
```

Comment: Hi thx for the solution. Curious how to make it enter 'full screen' mode with scaffold and all

Answer (score 3):

Neither the modal nor the persistent bottomsheets can be dragged into view. The persistent bottomsheet must be triggered open (e.g., by pressing a button) & THEN it may be dragged up & down until finally out of view. I wish there was an option to allow it to be dragged into view...

[Rubber](https://medium.com/@mattia_crovero/rubber-a-material-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-9f1bf519cc9a) should meet your needs; I gave it a try but it always freaks out when I call setstate (so a no go for me)... Let me know if you have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can show `DraggableScrollableSheet` as an `Overlay`.
Use the below function and pass a child widget that you want to show inside the bottomsheet.

```
 void openDraggableBottomSheet({required BuildContext context, required Widget child}) {
    OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.30,
          minChildSize: 0,
          maxChildSize: 0.9,
          snapSizes: const [0.30, 0.9],
          snap: true,
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              child: child,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
    // inserting overlay entry
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
  }
```